# JSF 2.2 HTML5 Friendly Markup for number fields

Tags: html, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

I'm learning JSF with HTML5 friendly markup. I want to receive a number in a text field:

```
<form jsf:id="form_item">
   <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label><input type="text" jsf:id="nombre" value="#{backend.item.nombre}"/>
   <label for="edad">Edad:</label> <input type="text" jsf:id="edad" value="#{backend.item.edad}"/>
   <input type="button" jsf:action="#{backend.addItem}" value="Agregar"/>;
</form>
```

Backend bean:

```
@Named(value = "backend")
@ViewScoped
public class Backend implements Serializable{

    private Item item;
    private List<Item> items;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of Backend
     */
    public Backend() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        this.item = new Item();
    }

    public void addItem(){
        this.getItems().add(item);
    }

//Setters and getters
```

Item bean:
    public class Item {

```
    private String nombre;
    private Integer edad;

    public Item(){
        this.nombre="";
        this.edad=0;
    }
 //Setters and getters
```

This code results in **java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String.**

Replacing the input text by h:inputText works:

```
<h:inputText id="edad" value="#{backend.item.edad}"/>
```

Do I have to give up HTML5 friendly markup in this case?

The app is running in GF4 Full profile.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to make this work using

```
<input type="text" jsf:id="edad" jsf:value="#{backend.item.edad}"/>
```

By adding jsf: before the value attribute, everything worked as expected. The JEE7 tutorial says in [8.9.1 Using Pass-through Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets009.htm#sthref379) that "specify at least one of its attributes using the http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf namespace", with an example showing the value property without the namespace. But it seems this only works if the bean property is a String.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want to make your attribute be "JSF-ish" you need to prefix it with the JSF namespace.  I'm glad you found the answer anyway!

Ed